# Firebase authentication how to generate UID with 15 characters instead of 28 by default?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, uid

I'm using firebase authentication to generate user. By default, the generated UID is always 28 characters. However, my customer wants it to be 15 characters instead. Is there a way to configure that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the way that Firebase Authentication assigns UIDs.

Comment: Do you have any document or reference which explained the reason for that, please?